# Should I add an allow all statement at the end of my robots.txt file?

Tags: seo, web-crawler, robots.txt, google-search-console

Do I need to add an allow all statement after my disallow statements in a robots.txt or do bots presume they can crawl anything that isn't marked as disallow.

Example:

```
User-Agent: *

Disallow: /folder1/
Disallow: /folder2/
Disallow: /folder3/
Disallow: /file1.php
Disallow: /file2.php

Allow: /

Sitemap: http://www.example.co.uk/sitemap.xml
```

or

```
User-Agent: *

Disallow: /folder1/
Disallow: /folder2/
Disallow: /folder3/
Disallow: /file1.php
Disallow: /file2.php

Sitemap: http://www.example.co.uk/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: You shouldn't have blank lines between `User-agent` and `Disallow`.

Comment: Thanks unor, hadn't noticed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly allow if your intent is to permit spiders to find everything except those items explicitly disallowed.

The disallow rules are there for the spider to determine whether something it has found should not be indexed - if there's no match in these rules for the address the spider is currently looking at, it gets indexed.

[Here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/robots.shtml) is a reasonably straightforward example page.